# BigQuery Storage Write API C# how to force sending / serializing default values

Tags: c#, serialization, google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm using BigQuery Storage Write API (C# net6). BigQuery Storage Write API use grpc/protobuf protocol to send data to BigQuery.

Protobuf (by default) do not serialize/send default values (like 0 for integers), so I got null on BigQuery when I send an integer with value 0.

My code:

```
syntax = "proto3"

message SomeModel  {
    int64 id = 1;
    int64 quantity = 2;
}
```

in order to send the data to BigQuery (using Storage Write API) I need to do this:

```
var records = new List<SomeModel>();
records.Add(new SomeModel{Id = 1, Quantity = 0});

var protoData = new AppendRowsRequest.Types.ProtoData
{
    WriterSchema = new ProtoSchema { ProtoDescriptor = SomeModel.Descriptor.ToProto() },
    Rows = new ProtoRows 
            { 
                SerializedRows = { records.Select(r => r.ToByteString()/*Serialization is made here*/ ) } 
            }
};
```

When data arrives to BigQuery table I got:

```
| id | quantity|
|--------------|
| 1  |  null   |
```

I want to store in BigQuery quantity = 0 **NOT** quantity = null.

**How can I force to send/serialize quantity = 0?**

or same question (more generic): **How can I force to send/serialize default values?**

Comment: Can you share what BigQuery documentation you followed on this one for proper replication?

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to [the **BigQuery Storage API** expecting protocol buffer data to be encoded in the proto2 wire format](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-storage/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/customer_record.proto#L16).

This is expected behavior of proto3 since, once a message is parsed, there is no way of telling whether a field was explicitly set to the [default value](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#default), or just not set at all.

Proto3 is not intended to replace proto2, it was created as an alternative for use cases and languages where proto2 is not available, and both language versions will be supported for the foreseeable future.

I would suggest using proto2 for this matter.

Comment: yes, I ended up changing all to proto2.